# Python - Performing OCR on MRZ (100% Accuracy) is possible?

Tags: python-3.x, ocr, passport-local, python-tesseract

I have used the code from [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/11/30/detecting-machine-readable-zones-in-passport-images/).

But what the problem yet I'm facing is `pytesseract` yet not providing 100% accurate output.

```
import from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

new = Image.open('Source Filename')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(new,lang="OCRB")

print(text)
```

I have also used MRZ font `OCRB.trainneddata` as seen in the code above.

Yet not 100% Output!

Please anyone have any clue how can I get the 100% accurate result?

Thanks

Comment: those will help you for MRZ [PassportEye](https://pypi.org/project/PassportEye/) and [mrz](https://pypi.org/project/mrz/)